# Python 3sum solution using itertools module exceeds time limit

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension, combinations, python-itertools

> Given an integer array nums, return all the triplets [nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]] such that i != j, i != k, and j != k, and nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0.
>
> Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

My solution passed 308/311 test cases, but exceeded the time limit when it got to 308. I used the itertools module and the `combinations` function to generate the list of 3 numbers and ran tests to filter them out according to the problem specifics.

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        import itertools
        x = itertools.combinations(nums, 3)
        y = [sorted(i) for i in x if (sum(i) == 0)]
        z = []
        [z.append(i) for i in y if i not in z]
        return z
```

How can I make it more efficient?

Comment: @mkrieger1 so the idea behind my solution is to generate all possible combinations of three numbers, and then drop the combinations that do not sum up to 0. Then finally I run a loop through the list of the combinations that pass the first test to filter out duplicates. The program I came up with does not return a list of None if there is a combination of three numbers in the list whose sum adds up to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```
def threeSum(nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    x = itertools.combinations(nums, 3)
    y = [sorted(i) for i in x if (sum(i) == 0)]
    z = []
    for i in y:
        if i not in z:
            z.append(i)
    return z
```

Notice that in the last few lines you keep appending to a list and checking whether the list contains an element.
This check requires to scan through the list one element at a time and check if the element is the one we are looking for.
Therefore, a linear number of comparisons in the length of the list.

There are data-structures that are more efficient at checking whether they contain an element or not.
An example of a possible alternative is:

```
def threeSum(nums: List[int]) -> FrozenSet[Tuple[int, int, int]]:
    return frozenset(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in itertools.combinations(nums, 3) if sum(i) == 0)
```

I tried to benchmark the two alternatives a bit.
I used as input the array of numbers from -100 to 100 and called each function 50 times i.e. `timeit.timeit(lambda: threeSum(nums), number=50)`.

In the first case the computation took 14 seconds, while using the second implementation the execution time was 6 seconds.

Finally, you are generating all triples and then filtering them based on the condition.
Directly generating the tuples that meet the requirements could lead to further performance improvements.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the frozenset alternative but it still doesn't pass all test cases and also exceeds the time limit on the 308th test case.

Comment: Have you tried directly generating only the triples that meet your requirements instead of generating all possible triples and then filtering them?

Comment: I do not know how to generate the triples

Comment: What about sorting the list `nums`.    
Then, you employ a first loop over the ordered values to pick the first element of the triple.   
Then, in a nested loop you iterate over the values greater than the one above.
If the sum of the two is greater than 0 then we can stop the iteration.

I believe that reasoning along these lines could lead to a solution.

Comment: That sounds like the beginning of a more efficient solution. Thank you